# Replace part of strings in multiple columns and tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have several fields in db containing url inside different strings, part of which I need to replace with another one.
F.e. the string is

```
abc::http://localhost:5000/pic/img/1.jpg|def:::blahblahblah_http://localhost:5000/hij/klm/hxyhgbcbxjgxz.jpeg:jgfgv/hgh/
```

I have many different strings like that.

I need to replace `http://localhost:5000` with `https://example.com` but leave everything else untouched.

Also I need to do that without stopping the database / on a working database.

I was thinking about doing smth like that:

```
UPDATE table01 
  SET field01 = replace(field01, 'http://localhost:5000', 'https://example.com')
```

How can I make this query include all strings in db, not only in table01 & field01, but all tables & all fields? Just want to make sure that there are no references left to this url at all.

Comment: just repeat this for all referenced columns. It only You could know - what filedXXX contain URL (if real column name contain some pattern - You can prepare queries with information schema, but must be sure)

Comment: @a_vlad what about all strings in db, all fields, rows & etc included? How do I do that? Is there any difference if it's json?

Comment: You leave a lot of out of the box - so it not possible to  answer for You full. For example - in Your string 2 http://localhost:5000, do You want replace both or only first? You can prepare list of target columns - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20194806/how-to-get-a-list-column-names-and-datatype-of-a-table-in-postgresql, and use this list for prepare list of final commands (again with query)

Comment: @a_vlad I want to replace "http://localhost:5000" with "https://example.com" in any place in db without any prepared list.  "Abc##http://localhost:5000" becomes "Abc##https://example.com" & 'Def$$http://localhost:5000/ghi/jkl/' becomes 'Def$$https://example.com/ghi/jkl'

Answer (score 4):

**First** of all, your `UPDATE` without `WHERE` clause is needlessly (very!) expensive. It would write a new row version for *all* rows, even where nothing changes. Only update rows that actually need an update!

```
UPDATE table01 
SET    field01 = replace(field01, 'http://localhost:5000', 'https://example.com')
WHERE  field01 ~ 'http://localhost:5000';
```

Related:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

**Next**, careful what you replace. You'll want to avoid **false positives**. Test before you apply it to the whole database. Your current expression:

```
replace(field01, 'http://localhost:5000', 'https://example.com')
```

would also change strings that probably shouldn't be changed. Like `'http://localhost:50000/pic/img/1.jpg'` (note: `50000` instead of `5000`)

To avoid that particular case:

```
regexp_replace(field01, 'http://localhost:5000\M', 'https://example.com', 'g')
```

Using regular expressions instead. `\M` at the end of the string, [per documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE),

> matches only at the end of a word

You may want to do more, depending on your exact requirements. So:

```
UPDATE table01 
SET    field01 =  regexp_replace(field01, 'http://localhost:5000\M'
                                        , 'https://example.com', 'g')
WHERE  field01 ~ 'http://localhost:5000\M';
```

**Then** apply to *all string columns* in a table. Ideally, only update each row once, to make this as cheap as possible. This plpgsql function executes the update for one given table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_replace_everywhere(_pattern text, _new_string text, _tbl regclass, OUT updated_rows int) AS
$func$
DECLARE
   -- basic string types, possibly extend with citext, domains or custom types:
   _typ  CONSTANT regtype[] := '{text, bpchar, varchar}';
   _sql  text;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO _sql     -- build command
          format('UPDATE %s SET %s WHERE %s'
               , _tbl
               , string_agg(format($$%1$s = regexp_replace(%1$s, $1, $2, 'g')$$, col), ', ')
               , string_agg(col || ' ~ $1', ' OR '))
   FROM  (
      SELECT quote_ident(attname) AS col
      FROM   pg_attribute
      WHERE  attrelid = _tbl            -- valid, visible, legal table name 
      AND    attnum >= 1                -- exclude tableoid & friends
      AND    NOT attisdropped           -- exclude dropped columns
      AND    NOT attnotnull             -- exclude columns defined NOT NULL!
      AND    atttypid = ANY(_typ)       -- only character types
      ORDER  BY attnum
      ) sub;

   -- Test
   -- RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql;

   -- Execute
   IF _sql IS NULL THEN
      updated_rows := 0;                         -- nothing to update
   ELSE
      EXECUTE _sql
      USING _pattern, _new_string;

      GET DIAGNOSTICS updated_rows = ROW_COUNT;  -- Report number of affected rows
   END IF;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call to apply to a single table:

```
SELECT f_replace_everywhere( 'http://localhost:5000\M'
                           , 'https://example.com'
                           , 'my_table');
```

Closely related with detailed explanation:

- [Replace empty strings with null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621897/replace-empty-strings-with-null-values/10686513#10686513)

**Finally**, apply to all relevant tables in our database. Don't touch system tables. You can loop through all tables based on `pg_tables` or `information_schema.tables`. See:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582500/how-to-check-if-a-table-exists-in-a-given-schema/24089729#24089729)

I'll leave that last step to you.

Comment: updated my original post

Comment: I have rolled back the question edit. The question was about string columns and has been answered. If you have a question about adjusting the answers for json, post a new question, with a link to this one.

Answer (score 1):

You could query the catalog for all columns that are long enough to hold that value, and generate and execute dynamic sql, eg.

```
DO $$
declare
  mysql varchar;
  Trec record;
  Crec record;
  vcomma varchar := '';
begin
  for Trec in SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables t
             where table_schema = 'public'
                -- and table_name = 't1'
               and table_type != 'VIEW'
               and exists ( select null from information_schema.columns c
                             where c.table_schema = t.table_schema
                             and c.table_name = t.table_name
                             and c.character_maximum_length >= 30)
  loop
    raise notice 'Current table is %', quote_ident(Trec.table_name);
    mysql := format('update %s set ',Trec.table_name);
    vcomma := '';
    for Crec in SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns c
             where table_schema = Trec.table_schema
               and c.table_name = Trec.table_name
               and c.character_maximum_length >= 30
    loop
      raise notice 'Current column is %', quote_ident(Crec.column_name);
      mysql := mysql || vcomma ||  Crec.column_name
               || ' = replace(' || Crec.column_name
               || ',' || '''http://the.olde.domain/the_olde_url'','
               || '''http://the.newer.domain/the_newer_url'')';
      vcomma := ', ';
    end loop;
    raise notice 'SQL is %', mysql;
    execute mysql;
  end loop;
end $$;
```

You can of course drop the "raise notice"'s.  One more thing, I ran this on a 9.6, don't know about 9.5.